# (HTML,PHP,MySQL) Ensure I have everything I need, Submitting Form Data

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, submit

I need to send my database over to the guy who has the server for a website that I'm managing. Problem is, I'm just now starting to learn PHP and MySQL after only really knowing HTML and CSS. I need to have a form submit data such as FirstName, LastName, Date of Birth, Telephone and etc. through PHP to a MySQL database. Security isn't highly important, as no credit card numbers or anything like that will be going through. But, I'd still like to know how to get the data secure.

Inside of my database, I have a table with all of the entries I need, (FirstName,LastName, DateofBirth, etc.) and I now need to send it to him, so it will be able to store information for the website it self. Here is the problem, I am not exactly sure I am going about the coding portion the correct way.
Here is my HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="insert.php" method="post">
<label>First Name: </label><input type="text" name="FirstName">
<label>Last Name:</label> <input type="text" name="LastName"> <br>
<label>Date of Birth:</label> <input type="date" name="DateofBirth">
<label>Telephone:</label> <input type="tel" maxlength="10" name ="Telephone">
<input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is insert.php

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("host","username","password","database");

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
    echo "Error, please try again later.";
    }

$sql="INSERT INTO table (FirstName, LastName, DateofBirth, Telephone)
VALUES
('$_POST[FirstName]',
'$_POST[LastName]',
'$_POST[DateofBirth]',
'$_POST[Telephone]')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{
die('Error, please try again later.';
}
echo "Successful";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Is this correct? Will it work the way that I am needing it to, to where I can pull the information from the table later on? Am I missing any highly crucial components of what I need?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is not correct. `$_Post['']` is not directly put in query and this is wrong way to insert data. You should be get data by variables. I have make insert file with database connection file please try this

```
    $host = "hostname";
    $user = "username";
    $pwd = "password";
    $db = "databasename";

$connect = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pwd) or die('Could not connect');
$db = mysql_select_db($db);
$firstname = $_REQUEST['FirstName'];
$lastname = $_REQUEST['LastName'];
$date = $_REQUEST['DateofBirth'];
$telephone = $_REQUEST['Telephone'];
$sql="INSERT INTO `table` (`FirstName`, `LastName`, `DateofBirth`, `Telephone`)VALUES('".$firstname."','".$lastname."','".$date."','".$telephone."')";
if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{
    die('Error, please try again later.');
}else{
    echo "Successful";
}
```